# thinking about writing a spell bee solver program

Tags: python

Alright I have been thinking of creating a spell bee solver program on python which takes the letters as input and gives the all the possible words in output.
so, I have been thinking of using this English dictionary library for referencing words (https://pypi.org/project/english-dictionary/).
but the things that worries me is that for spell bee the words can be both smaller and larger than the provided set of letters and reoccurrence of letters is also a possibility.
so, what kind of loop should I run in order to include all the possible senerios?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to find words for all possible subsets of the set of letters. You could use itertools to generate these subsets.

```
import itertools

letters = ['a', 'c', 'n']
for i in range(1, len(letters) + 1):
    combinations = list(itertools.combinations(letters, i))
    generate_words(combinations) # implement this how you were planning to
```